# Xbox: Send text message when friends online

Tags: xbox-network

He there,

Is there a way in xbox to send your cellphone a text message when your friends are online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feature in Xbox Live that informs your cellphone when your friends are online via text message. However, there are smartphone applications that might let you see the status of your Xbox Live friends on your smartphone, and this option will be integrated in upcoming Windows Phone 7 platform.

Comment: Thanks, I do have an iPhone and have looked up several apps such as 360Live. I will see if they support push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do you one better:

You can now message Xbox Live friends via [Xbox.com](http://live.xbox.com/en-US/MessageCenter/Compose?gamertag=Jim%200).

This means any device that can connect to Xbox.com (ie most smart phones) can message and receive messages sent to their own accounts.

In your case you'd message their xbox live account normally, and they would receive it the next time they checked their account on xbox.com.  I realize this is a pull system (instead of the standard push), but it does come in handy

Comment: Notice, however, that you must have a Xbox Live Gold account in order to send messages through the xbox.com website.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a Gold account, I will check this out.